# Templating embedded forms

Tags: php, templates, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

You have many choices to render a form in Symfony.
One way would be:

```
<?php foreach($form as $input): ?>
    // do rengerLabel, render, etc.
<?php endforeach ?>
```

That's great because my form renders all the errors and inputs by the same, but it also renders the embedded form. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid rendering the fields one by one and finally run the foreach in `$form[embedded]` as `$input`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like:

```
$embeded_form = $form[embedded];
unset($form[embeded]);

foreach($form as $input) {
   // do rengerLabel, render, etc.
}

foreach($embeded_form as $input) {
   // do rengerLabel, render, etc. for embeded form
}
```